# Need help to clean data - python multiple groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a huge dataframe and they are many typos for the spelling of names.

This dataframe I been working on

```
  First     Last     Location      ID1              ID2
  John      Smith    Calgary       JohnCalgary      SmithCalgary
  John      Smith    Toronto       JohnToronto      SmithToronto
  Joh       Smith    Toronto       JohToronto       SmithToronto
  Steph     Sax      Vancouver     StephVancouver   SaxVancouver
  Steph     Sa       Vancouver     StephVancouver   SaVancouver
  Victor    Jones    Toronto       VictorToronto    JonesToronto
  Stacy     Lee      Markham       StacyMarkham     LeeMarkham
  Stac      Lee      Markham       StacMarkham      LeeMarkham
  Stacy     Lee      Calgary       StacyCalgary     LeeCalgary
```

This is the code

```
data = {'First':['John', 'John', 'Joh', 'Steph','Steph','Victor','Stacy','Stac','Stacy'],
    'Last':['Smith','Smith','Smith','Sax','Saxe','Jones','Lee','Lee','Lee'],
     'Location':['Caglary','Toronto','Toronto','Vancouver','Vancouver','Toronto','Markham','Markham','Calgary'],
     'ID1': ['JohnCalgary', 'JohnToronto', 'JohToronto', 'StephVancouver','StephVancouver',VictorToronto', 'StacyMarkham', 'StacMarkham',StacyCalgary'],
     'ID2':['SmithCalgary','SmithToronto', 'SmithToronto', 'SaxeVancouver', 'SaVancouver', 'JonesToronto', 'LeeMarkham', 'LeeMarkham', 'LeeCalgary']
    }
```

Even trying to do a groupby using ID1 and ID2 where if the ID2 matches another ID2 and the first name is different and vice verse - there are still so many typos so I need to filter more.

How can I make it so that where

- ID1 - Matches another ID1 and the Last3 are the same
- ID2 - Matches another ID2 and the First 3 are the same

Desired, narrowed down dataset

```
   First     Last     Location      ID1              ID2             First3   Last3
   John      Smith    Toronto       JohnToronto      SmithToronto    Joh      Smi
   Joh       Smith    Toronto       JohToronto       SmithToronto    Joh      Smi
   Steph     Sax      Vancouver     StephVancouver   SaxVancouver    Ste      Sax
   Steph     Sa       Vancouver     StephVancouver   SaxeVancouver   Ste      Sax 
   Stacy     Lee      Markham       StacyMarkham     LeeMarkham      Sta      Lee
   Stac      Lee      Markham       StacMarkham      LeeMarkham      Sta      Lee
```

This is what I was trying so far

```
 m1 = df10.groupby('ID1')['ID2'],('Last3').transform('nunique').gt(1)

 m2 = df10.groupby('ID2')['ID1']('First3').transform('nunique').gt(1)

 out10 = df10[m1|m2]
```

Comment: have you tried using multipe groupbys `df10.groupby(['ID1','ID2','Last3'])` and seeing if that gets you closer to your desired output

Comment: tried didn't work...

Comment: Can you share expected output?